# How to cut polygon shape sprite in Multiple Sprite Editor Unity

Tags: unity, sprites, spritesheet

Here is a sprite I have taken from internet and trying to slice it out in many smaller pieces.

But the problem is I have polygon shape sprite, how to cut it out, selected in picture ?

[image]

Rest are just fine.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @iQew I think that's worth writing as an answer.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know, if I could do it inside Unity ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to do this? Just move the top right part in a programm like photoshop or gimp and then let Unity slice it automatically. If you later need collision detection on that ground, you can create an edge collider.

I don't think there is way to slice something into a non-rectangle form. Otherwise please correct me.